# Print message in the repository randomly

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have been trying to print the message stored with the `jpaRepository` but without luck I couldnt do it and googled it as well and I just don't understand :)
I did tried to do and play using a `ListArray` which have dont the trick it goes;

```
@RequestMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
public String home() {  

   ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList();
   List.add(msg1.getContent());
   List.add(msg.getContent());

   Random random = new Random();
   int index = random.nextInt(List.size());

   return List.get(index);
}
```

So, when accessing the `index` i get randomly what is in the array, but I would love to know how would I implement this with a `jpaRepository`, i did this;

```
@RequestMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
public String home() {

   HelloMessage msg = new HelloMessage();
   msg.setContent("Hello");
   HelloMessageRepository.save(msg);

   HelloMessage msg1 = new HelloMessage();
   msg1.setContent("World");
   helloMessageRepository.save(msg1);

   return ??;
}
```

So the problem here is how would i return to get randomly the strings within the repository? Kindly help, appreciated.

Comment: The "repository" is nothing to do with the JPA API. It is Spring Data JPA API. Tags fixed

Comment: that just shows how good i am with this. thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time seeing what you want to use this for, but I think I have a solution.

If you look at JpaRepository hierarchy, you will see that it implement PagingAndSortingRepository which means that it supports pagination, so you could do the following to select a random page of size one:

```
Random random = new Random();
// guard against 0 entities
int index = random.nextInt((int) helloMessageRepository.count() +1);
List<HelloMessage> list = helloMessageRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(index, 1));
HelloMessage msg = list.getContent().get(0);
```

Assuming no one suddenly removes entries from the DB, something like this should work (I have not tested the code, so it may require adjustment, and you need special handling if the DB is empty).

Comment: hi, i tried the code but im having a compatibility issue with `List<HelloMessage>` here is my code kindly check http://pastebin.com/qY6hssf0 . and thanx for answering.